# Searching a bitonic array with roughly $2\log n$ comparisons

Tags: search-algorithms

I don't know how to search a bitonic array with roughly $2\log n$ comparisons in the worst case.

What I am trying now is to find the maximum integer using roughly $\log n$ comparisons (binary search) — this divides the array into the increasing and decreasing pieces. Then apply binary search again to these two pieces. So, it takes roughly $3\log n$ comparisons in worst case.

How to do it with roughly $2\log n$ comparisons without finding the maximum integer first? May you give me some hints?

Comment: `find the maximum` is it guaranteed that the "inner" extremum is a maximum? Are duplicate values allowed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered on [so]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372930/given-a-bitonic-array-and-element-x-in-the-array-find-the-index-of-x-in-2logn

Comment: @YuvalFilmus This question is suitable for both sites, so just [leave it open](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4713/463392).

Comment: It's suitable on both sites, but it is only answered on one site, which is not this site.

Comment: @greybeard, No duplicate values. anyway, I saw Yuval Filmus comment. Somehow there is no redirect post to other community. I may leave this post here then.